# Issues to filtre data from a data frame

Tags: r, filter

I am still novice regarding R programming and I have some issues to filtre some data from a data frame. To sum up, I have a data frame with 7 columns and more than 8760 rows.

```r
> mydata_B01 <- read.csv2(file = "analysis_spectro_1.csv")
> head(mydata_B01)
      Date         Value     Unit      RadLevel FlowLowOrHigh Maintenance Valid
1 01-01-2018 00:00 1.028e-07 mol       NA            NA       FALSE       TRUE
2 01-01-2018 01:00 1.050e-07 mol       NA            NA       FALSE       TRUE
3 01-01-2018 02:00 1.030e-07 mol       NA            NA       FALSE       TRUE
4 01-01-2018 03:00 0         mol       NA            NA       FALSE       TRUE
5 01-01-2018 03:30 1.040e-07 mol       NA            NA       FALSE       TRUE
6 01-01-2018 04:00 1.009e-07 mol       NA            NA       TRUE        FALSE
        ....
```

Each hour during 1 year, the device took a measure.
From this data frame, I select the rows 1, 2, 6 and 7 because I will need them later in the script.

```r
A_B01 <- na.omit(mydata_B01["Date"])
B_B01 <- na.omit(mydata_B01["Value"])
C_B01 <- na.omit(mydata_B01["Maintenance"])
D_B01 <- na.omit(mydata_B01["Valid"])
```

Now, I would like to obtain a data frame containing only the rows of mydata_B01 when these 4 conditions are altogether met:

- "Value" = ou > than 0,
- AND "Maintenance" is "FALSE",
- AND "Valid" is "TRUE",
- AND when the "Date" column contains ":00"

Because actually, for some days, the device took a measure every 30 minuts, but I wish to have only one measure per hour. In other words, I would like to get rid of rows containing ..:30 for the "Date" column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the package `dplyr` gives you an easy solution:

```r
mydata_B01 %>%
  filter(Value > 0 & 
         Maintenance == TRUE & 
         Valid == TRUE & 
         grepl(":00", Date))
```

Using only base R

```r
mydata_B01[mydata_B01$Value > 0 & 
           mydata_B01$Maintenance == TRUE & 
           mydata_B01$Valid == TRUE & 
           grepl(":00", mydata_B01$Date),]
```

or

```r
subset(mydata_B01, 
       mydata_B01$Value > 0 & 
       mydata_B01$Maintenance == TRUE & 
       mydata_B01$Valid == TRUE & 
       grepl(":00", mydata_B01$Date))
```

As @akrun mentioned, since `Maintenance` and `Valid` are boolean, the conditions above are simplified to

```r
Value > 0 & 
Maintenance & 
Valid  & 
grepl(":00", Date)
```

and

```r
mydata_B01$Value > 0 & 
mydata_B01$Maintenance & 
mydata_B01$Valid  & 
mydata_B01$grepl(":00", Date)
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Ho finally this works perfectly:

```
Corrected_my_data <- subset(mydata_B01, 
       mydata_B01$Value > 0 & 
       mydata_B01$Maintenance == TRUE & 
       mydata_B01$Valid == TRUE & 
       grepl(":00", mydata_B01$Date))
```

I just have to change "Maintenance == TRUE" by "Maintenance == FALSE" :)
Thanks both of you for your help !